# Share Facebook permissions between Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm developing an App for Android and iOS. One of the permissions I ask from Facebook is for the user friends, but since you can only get the friends that also gave permissions to your App and since I had to register an App of iOS and one of Android in Facebook from iOS I can only get the users that are using my App on iOS.

How can I get all the friends that gave permission of my App regardless of the platform?

Comment: You should use the same app id for both iOS and Android, and you should be able to see friends from both platforms (and www as well, if you have that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register your app with Facebook (a requirement to access the Facebook SDK), you can register multiple platforms (such as iOS and Android). You can then use the same developer ID in both your iOS and Android apps, which should give you what you're asking.